# docker-compose to a remote host using ssh fails in gitlab ci

Tags: docker, ssh, docker-compose, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm unable to docker-compose successfully on a remote host using SSH from a gitlab CI/CD pipeline runner.

docker-compose fails with the following errors :

```
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
```

I'm not able to repro the issue outside Gitlab. Meaning, I tried on my local machine by running the same docker image my gitlab deploy step use, do the exact same commands in my script manually and it worked like a charm...

I'm even trying the ssh config in the script by connecting to the host and printing `docker version` and it succeeds properly.

#### deploy_to_staging.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

apk update
apk add openssh-client
apk add --update bash

eval $(ssh-agent -s)
mkdir -p ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh
# copy the server private key
echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY"
echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | ssh-add -
# copy server host key .pub file from /etc/ssh/ and paste it into this variable
echo "$SSH_SERVER_HOSTKEYS"
ssh-keyscan -p 12345 11.222.3.444
ssh-keyscan -p 12345 11.222.3.444 >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts

ssh root@11.222.3.444 -p 12345 "docker version; exit"

# Docker-compose app and db
docker-compose --verbose -H "ssh://root@11.222.3.444:12345" -f docker-compose.staging.yml up -d --build

exit
```

#### gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: alpine:latest

services:
  - docker:dind

stages:
  - build
  - package
  - deploy

[...]

deploy:
  image: docker/compose:alpine-1.28.2
  stage: deploy
  environment:
    name: staging
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - sh deploy_to_staging.sh
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: did you find out what the problem was? I'm having similar issues..

Comment: @kodlan unfortunately no. I can't reproduce this issue outside Gitlab so I'm stuck...

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem, depending on your configuration it might work or not. Basically, i created a user `deployer` on my server which I was trying to ssh to.

Since i had forgotten to add this new user (`deployer`) to the `docker` usergroup, he had no docker permissions. So basically all I did was

```
[root@myserver ~]# groupadd docker
groupadd: group 'docker' already exists
[root@myserver ~]# usermod -aG docker deployer
```